# Running Ubuntu on a VM as a server in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machines

I am currently developing a django application on my local computer and therefore I need to setup a server. Since Apache/Python is very comfortable to work with on a Linux based system, and my local computer has Windows 7 installed, I've decided to install a VM (using VM Player) with ubuntu.

I installed Apache/MySQL/Python/Django on ubuntu and it works just fine. However, I would like to keep coding in Windows and to be able to connect to the ubuntu server though Windows. That is, that I will be able to open a browser window and connect to the site on the ubuntu server.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
Meir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up the VM to connect to a bridged or host-only ethernet interface, you will be able to connect to the vm from Windows, it will be accessable like a different computer in the network.

You could set up a FTP server, which can be accessed by Windows. Also, many IDEs are able to automatically upload to an FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Some ubuntu-versions are setup with a firewall, so you have to configure this for your convenience.

And don't forget to configure your apache/MySQL or other services/daemons so that they accept requests from a network-device (not only from 127.0.0.1 / localhost).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out the vagrant project. They make it really easy to set up "dev server" vm's:

http://vagrantup.com/